# filter() and some() don't return expected value

Tags: javascript, angular, filter

I'm creating a filtering method to filter a dataset I get from the API.

the Array to filter, has objects with many parameters, but I want to base my filter only on specified parameters.

example:

```
 let Cars: Array = [{name: "volvo", color:"red", year: "1999"}, {name: "vw", color:"blue", year: "2000"}];
```

my filtering function:

```
  filterAPIResponse(data: any, textToFilter: string):any {

    const keysToFilter = ["name", "color"];

    if(textToFilter) {

    return data.filter(obj => (keysToFilter.some(val => {
        obj[val].toLowerCase().includes(textToFilter.toLowerCase());
      })));

      } else {
      return data;
    }
  }
```

so this returns always an empty array, even if I Call:

```
this.filterAPIResponse(Cars, "volv");
```

here I expect that `"volv"` matches the car `"volvo"`,

and indeed console.log of  `obj[val].toLowerCase().includes(textToFilter.toLowerCase());` does return true, but the array at the end is empty.

So that must mean I made a mistake between the `filter()` and the `some()` and I dont see it?

Comment: to be more clear, do  `val => { return <condition> }` or `val => <condition>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments, I've added a `return` to the some callback. Otherwise the returned value would always be `undefined` and [`array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) would always return an empty array.

```js
let cars = [{name: "volvo", color:"red", year: "1999"}, {name: "vw", color:"blue", year: "2000"}]

function filterAPIResponse(data, textToFilter) {
    const keysToFilter = ["name", "color"]
    if(textToFilter) {
      /* The return
      return data.filter(obj => keysToFilter.some(val => {
        return obj[val].toLowerCase().includes(textToFilter.toLowerCase())
      }))
      /*/ // Or the one-liner
      return data.filter(obj => keysToFilter.some(val =>
        obj[val].toLowerCase().includes(textToFilter.toLowerCase())
      ))
      //*/
    } else {
      return data
    }
  }

console.log(this.filterAPIResponse(cars, "volv"))
```

Comment: so basically all I was missing was, removing the {} brackets from the some() part? I'm not still sure why those brackets would break the code

Comment: ok I think that when you add brackets, you need to specify a return, but when you keep it in "one line", the return is assumed? is that right? anyway thank you, this solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

you don't have a return statement from the some function. 
you have 2 options:
1. add the some function in one line, in that way you don't need a return statement.
2. add return statement.
I didn't test the code, but it seems that's the problem.